# C++ DirectX 11 Memory Management Concerns with releasing ShaderResourceView

Tags: c++, memory, directx, textures

I'm looking at my Task Manager's Processes and I can see that when I start up my project it uses 2.2k memory and when I load a texture it raises to 2.7k, but when I release the texture resource, delete the texture class object the applications memory decreases to 2.5k. I'm very worried about this memory that isn't being released and was hoping someone could fill me in on what I'm doing wrong, or perhaps there's a garbage collector that will release this over time that I don't know about? Or maybe Task Manager Processes is just not a practical way to determine the memory my application uses?

Here I initialize my texture class and load my texture, then I immanently release it (for testing purposes).

```
test = 0;

test = new Texture2D;

test->Initialize(m_DX3D->GetDevice(), "../3rd Year Project/Content/Fonts/DialogFont");

//break here

test->Shutdown();
delete test;
test = 0;
```

//Texture2D.cpp

```
bool Texture2D::Initialize(
_In_ ID3D11Device* device, 
_In_ LPCSTR path)
{
HRESULT result;

char buffer[256];

strncpy(buffer, path,     sizeof(buffer));
strncat(buffer, ".png",   sizeof(buffer));

result = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(device, buffer, NULL, NULL, &m_texture, NULL);

if(FAILED(result))
    return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: The task manager's definitely not a good way to measure memory consumption, particularly on a scale that small. You're dealing with a scale smaller than a single page of virtual memory here. Realistically, you should probably run anything like this in a loop several hundred times and see if the working set size grows linearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - the task manager is not an appropriate tool. It shows only how much memory the application has reserved for it, not, how much of the reserved memory it is actually using!

You can detect memory leaks over the run time with it only if memory usage is steadily growing up to sizes that are unreasonable, so you are in need for a better tool.

I point out to [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) just because it was mentioned at [this thread here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490718/track-memory-usage-in-c-and-evaluate-memory-consumption), you would have to evaluate it on your own...